# FomulaArray causes Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I try to use the fomulaArray function in VBA and always receive the above mentioned error. I am aware that 255 characters are the limit for the fomulaArray, but it doesn't even give me the error that the fomular is out of range, I assume tht there must be some other mistake.

The fomular works in its original form, when I use it outside VBA in Excel.

```
Worksheets("Last Week").Range("AJ6:AJ1500").FormulaArray = "=IF(AND(F6="""",I6=""Projects""),MIN(IF((O7:O31=O6)*(NOT(G7:G31=""Yes""))*(NOT(G7:G31=""Not OK""))*(NOT(G7:G31=""postponed""))*(NOT(G7:G31=""""))*(NOT(H7:H31=""delayed""))*(NOT(F7:F31=""Failure"")),AJ7:AJ31)),IF(F6="""","""",IF(AH6>0,14,IF(AE6>0,13,IF(AC6>0,12,IF(AB6>0,11,IF(AA6>0,10,IF(Z6>0,9,IF(V6>0,8,IF(U6>0,7,IF(Y6>0,6,IF(X6>0,5,IF(W6>0,4,IF(T6>0,3,IF(S6>0,2,IF(R6>0,1,0))))))))))))))))"
```

I've added double "" everywhere and replaced ";" with ",". I am right now clueless what causes error 1004.

Once I would know the cause of the error I would try to split the formula into two variables as a workaround for FormulaArrays limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular formula that uses AGGREGATE:

```
Worksheets("Last Week").Range("AJ6:AJ1500").Formula = "=IF(AND(F6="""",I6=""Projects""),AGGREGATE(15,6,AJ7:AJ31/((O7:O31=O6)*(NOT(G7:G31=""Yes""))*(NOT(G7:G31=""Not OK""))*(NOT(G7:G31=""postponed""))*(NOT(G7:G31=""""))*(NOT(H7:H31=""delayed""))*(NOT(F7:F31=""Failure""))),1),IF(F6="""","""",IF(AH6>0,14,IF(AE6>0,13,IF(AC6>0,12,IF(AB6>0,11,IF(AA6>0,10,IF(Z6>0,9,IF(V6>0,8,IF(U6>0,7,IF(Y6>0,6,IF(X6>0,5,IF(W6>0,4,IF(T6>0,3,IF(S6>0,2,IF(R6>0,1,0))))))))))))))))"
```

Comment: I've tried this option today and in the beginning it looked great, but in the end it doesn't show me the MIN value of the array at the top. The issue here is, that i have different groups and i want to see the MIN value at the header row of each grop (AJ6). Right now I only see values in the rows between the group headers.